# Using glob recursion to get sub directories and files containing CSVs

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I am trying to concat multiple CSVs that live in subfolders of my parent directory.

```
/ParentDirectory
│  
│
├───SubFolder 1
│       test1.csv
│
├───SubFolder 2
│       test2.csv
│
├───SubFolder 3
│       test3.csv
│       test4.csv
│
├───SubFolder 4
│       test5.csv
```

When I do

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

files = glob.glob('/ParentDirectory/*.csv', recursive=True)
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fp) for fp in files], ignore_index=True)
```

I get `ValueError: No objects to concatenate`.

But if I select a specific sub folder, it works:

```
files = glob.glob('/ParentDirectory/SubFolder 3/*.csv', recursive=True)
```

How come `glob` isn't able to go down a directory and get the CSVs within each folder of the parent directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
files = glob.glob('/ParentDirectory/**/*.csv', recursive=True)
```

Comment: What if there are subdirectories in the subdirectories though? i.e., is this a specified number of subdirectories or will it iterate through all that it finds?

Comment: @MSD that will get the entire subdirectory tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
files = glob.glob('/ParentDirectory/*/*.csv')
```

It doesn't need to be recursive for that pattern, but does need a wildcard for the subdirectory.

Comment: What if there are subdirectories in the subdirectories though? i.e., is this a specified number of subdirectories or will it iterate through all that it finds?

Comment: Your example doesn't have that, but if you have a more complicated example you should be specific about it.  @Ric answer is the recursive version if you have subdirs of subdirs.  This will find the files for your example, i.e. only one level of subdirectories.